# Sort array of String containing MonthYear combination

Tags: objective-c, sorting, nsarray

I have the following Array of String.

```
 NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"042018, 052018, 122018, 012019, 022019, 032019"];
```

I want to sort this array in order as of MonthYear combination i.e 032019 comes before 122018.

Result should give

```
(
    032019,
    022019,
    012019,
    122018,
    052018,
    042018
)
```

I tried this code but not giving a satisfactory results. Please help.

```
            NSDateFormatter *fmtDate = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
                    [fmtDate setDateFormat:@"mmyyyy"];
            NSComparator compareDates = ^(id string1, id string2)
                    {
                        NSDate *date1 = [fmtDate dateFromString:string1];
                        NSDate *date2 = [fmtDate dateFromString:string2];
                        return [date1 compare:date2];
                    };
            NSArray *sortedYearKeys = [[dicSection allKeys] sortedArrayUsingComparator:compareDates];
            NSLog(@"array:%@",sortedYearKeys);
```

Comment: `return [date2 compare:date1];` instead?

Comment: Consider to use the format `yyyyMM` which is directly sortable.

Comment: I tried your code and if I return `[date2 compare:date1]`, like Larme said, then it works.

Answer (score -1):

This is for anyone who has this kind of strange  requirements,
In Words, What I have done is, I have added static 01 as Date for each string and then applied Date sorting then once I got my desired results I want it in reverse order so I inversed the result array and then I will remove the extra 01 which I have added earlier.

```
        NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[dicSection allKeys]];
        int i =0;
        for(;i<(int)array.count;){
            NSString *str = [array objectAtIndex:i];
            str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"01%@",str];
            [array replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:str];
            i++;
        }

        NSDateFormatter *fmtDate = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
                [fmtDate setDateFormat:@"ddmmyyyy"];
        NSComparator compareDates = ^(id string1, id string2)
                {
                    NSDate *date1 = [fmtDate dateFromString:string1];
                    NSDate *date2 = [fmtDate dateFromString:string2];
                    return [date1 compare:date2];
                };
        NSArray *sortedYearMothKeys = [array sortedArrayUsingComparator:compareDates];
        sortedYearMothKeys = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[sortedYearMothKeys reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects]];
```

Comment: This answer is far too complicated.

Answer (score -1):

I figured out your problem. There are actually two problems.

1. The `array` contains only one object which is `NSString`, so first you need to convert that string into `NSArray`, I mean you need to separate the inner date objects.

Which you can do it by `NSString`'s method `componentsSeparatedByString`.

2. After you separate the objects there is still one whitespace added with each object which causes the issue while comparing the date objects.

So you need to remove all whitespace from the string before converting it into array components.

1. Let's see it one by one. your given array.

   ```
   NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"042018, 052018, 122018, 012019, 022019, 032019"];
   ```
2. Get string from this array

   ```
   NSString *dateString = array[0];
   ```
3. Now, this string contains whitespace which is an issue here.

   ```
   // Remove extra characters like whitespace from your string

   NSString *dateString = array[0];
   //Output: 042018, 052018, 122018, 012019, 022019, 032019

   NSString *trimmedString = [dateString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
   //Output: 042018,052018,122018,012019,022019,032019
   ```

You can observe the whitespace in above output which is removed in `trimmedString`.

4. Convert string into the array:

   ```
   NSArray *dateArray = [trimmedString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
   ```
5. And, final step sort this array

   ```
    NSArray *sortedArray = [dateArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSString *obj1, NSString *obj2) {
       NSDateFormatter *formatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
       [formatter setDateFormat:@"MMyyyy"];

       NSDate *date1 = [formatter dateFromString:obj1];
       NSDate *date2 = [formatter dateFromString:obj2];
       return ([date1 compare:date2] == NSOrderedAscending) ? YES : NO;
   }];

   NSLog(@"sortedArray :%@\n", sortedArray);

   // Output: (
      032019,
      022019,
      012019,
      122018,
      052018,
      042018
   )
   ```

If you wish to convert it into a string, you can do it by using method `componentsJoinedByString`

```
NSString *sortedString = [sortedArray componentsJoinedByString:@", "];
```

Note that I have added one extra space after `,` to match your desired result.

```
//Output: 032019, 022019, 012019, 122018, 052018, 042018
```

Comment: You don't have to remove the whitespace: `dateArray = [dateString componentsSeparatedByString:@", "]`

Comment: The `NSComparator` block should return a `NSComparisonResult`, not a `BOOL`.

Comment: It's faster to create one formatter outside the block.

Comment: @Willeke: Without removing whitespace the code will not work, please implement this code and check. don't comment blindly. Have you checked this code?

Comment: I tried `dateArray = [dateString componentsSeparatedByString:@", "]` and it works. Did you try it? `array` isn't used in the question and is probably an error, it should be `[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"042018", @"052018", @"122018", @"012019", @"022019", @"032019", nil]`.

Comment: @Willeke See this is your assumption that it should be an array. We can not change the things that OP asked. I don't write code just as it is. I wrote this code and see also wrote the output after each execution of the code. I would suggest you read SO policy about how to behave in this community.

Comment: I'm sorry. I did not comment blindly and I did check your code. What I tried to say is removing the whitespace is not neccecary if the code is `dateArray = [dateString componentsSeparatedByString:@", "]`, with a space in `@", "`.

Comment: @Willeke: Pardon me, if I sound like rude. I agree with you in that case.